# Double clicking on WPF Datagrid crashes the program

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to do something when I double click on a row in datagrid. I can do this with **AutoGenerateColumns="False"** but when I tried with **AutoGenerateColumns="True"** , double clicking on a row crashes the program. below is my code.

**The XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp6"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Loaded="grid_Loaded" MouseDoubleClick="grid_MouseDoubleClick">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="User Name" Binding="{Binding UserName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
 private void grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataClassesDataContext connection = new DataClassesDataContext();

                var query = (from operators in connection.SWOperators
                             select new
                             {
                                 operators.FirstName,
                                 operators.UserName,
                                 operators.Type
                             }).ToList();

                grid.ItemsSource = query;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
        }

        private void grid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Double click event is triggered.");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }

        }
```

**This is the text from Call stack while debugging**

```
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'c:\users\kamal\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WpfApp6\WpfApp6\bin\Debug\WpfApp6.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'WpfApp6.App..ctor'
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'WpfApp6.App.InitializeComponent'
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Kamal\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudio.XamlDiagnostics.9512\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemData.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApp6.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApp6.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>WpfApp6.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'UserName' of type '&amp;lt;&amp;gt;f__AnonymousType0`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]'.</Message><StackTrace>   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.CheckReadOnly(Object item, Object info)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.ReplaceItem(Int32 k, Object newO, Object parent)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32 k, ICollectionView collectionView, Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.AttachDataItem()
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt attempt)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.BeginEdit(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedBeginEdit(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedBeginEdit(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e, CommandBinding commandBinding)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.Execute(Object parameter, IInputElement target)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.BeginEdit(RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at WpfApp6.App.Main()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidOperationException: A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'UserName' of type '&amp;lt;&amp;gt;f__AnonymousType0`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]'.
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.CheckReadOnly(Object item, Object info)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.ReplaceItem(Int32 k, Object newO, Object parent)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32 k, ICollectionView collectionView, Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.AttachDataItem()
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt attempt)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean lastChance)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.BeginEdit(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedBeginEdit(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedBeginEdit(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e, CommandBinding commandBinding)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.Execute(Object parameter, IInputElement target)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.BeginEdit(RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&amp;amp; handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at WpfApp6.App.Main()</ExceptionString><DataItems><Data></Data></DataItems></Exception></TraceRecord>
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'UserName' of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]'.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It does not throw any exception. I have updated the question with call stack text. Please see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception message is telling you that you bound a read only property with a two-way binding:

```
<Message>A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only 
    property 'UserName' of type '&amp;lt;&amp;gt;f__AnonymousType0`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]'.
</Message>
```

Looks like that's this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Header="User Name" 
    Binding="{Binding UserName}">
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

So change it to a one-way binding.

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Header="User Name" 
    Binding="{Binding UserName, Mode=OneWay}">
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

You may need to do the same with other columns bound to properties of the same anonymous type objects.

You may want to make the column read-only as well:

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Header="User Name" 
    IsReadOnly="True"
    Binding="{Binding UserName, Mode=OneWay}">
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Always find the exception message; you usually can, and on the rare occasions when it doesn't  lead you straight to the answer, it'll get you a long way closer to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Marked this as the answer.